# Servlet works in eclipse, but not in Apache Tomcat. Unable to infer base url....API is behind API Gateway

Tags: web-services, servlets

Please help and thank you in advance. For the past 3 days, I had been looking into this issue in stackoverflow and elsewhere. I need to have 2 urls for my web application. It works in eclipse but it does not work when deployed to apache-tomcat (8.5.16). SpringBootVersion 2.0.9, SpringVersion 5.0.13.
The web-services methods do not work, and swagger keeps popping the message: "Unable to infer base url. This is common when using dynamic servlet registration or when the API is behind an API Gateway". This is a working application without the servlet registration shown below.

```
    public class MyWsApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
        // other configurations here
        // servlet registration below
        @Bean
        public DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet() {
            return new DispatcherServlet();
        }
        @Bean
        public ServletRegistrationBean<DispatcherServlet> servletRegistration() {
            String url1 = "/web-services-url1/*";
            String url2 = "/services_url2/*";
            ServletRegistrationBean<DispatcherServlet> registration = new ServletRegistrationBean<>(dispatcherServlet(),
                    url1, url2);
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>(); 

            params.put("contextClass", "org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext");
            registration.setInitParameters(params);
            return registration;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all who read my question. I have solved this by defining 2 application contexts in tomcat. All those java code is not needed for adding an url. Solution:
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Naming